# Malformed IP Scapy

Tags: networking, udp, ip, scapy

My goal is to develop a script that can send IP packets to any host to any other host in a different subnet. Right now everything is seemingly working, except my IP packet is malformed so scapy cannot send it.

```
def sendIPMessage(interfaceName, dst_ip, routerIP, message):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind(("", port))

    src_addr = get_mac_address(interface=interfaceName)

    my_ip = get_ip_address(interfaceName)
    netmask = ipaddress.ip_address(dst_ip) in ipaddress.ip_network(my_ip)
    if netmask is True:  # if dst is in the same network
        arp_MAC = sendArpMesage(interfaceName, dst_ip)
    else:
        arp_MAC = sendArpMesage(interfaceName, routerIP)

    ether = Ether(src=str(src_addr), dst=str(arp_MAC))
    print(ether.show())

    size = len(message) + 14
    ip = IP(src=my_ip, dst=dst_ip, proto=17, ihl=5, len=size, ttl=5, chksum=0)
    #print(ip.show())

    payload = Raw(message)

    packet = ether / ip / msg
    del packet[IP].chksum
    packet = packet.__class__(bytes(packet)) # same as packet.show2()

    print(packet.show())

    success = send(packet)

    if success is not None:
        print(success.show)
    else:
        print("success is None")
```

Here is the show() information

```
Begin emission:
*Finished sending 1 packets.

Received 1 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 0 packets
###[ Ethernet ]### 
  dst       = 4e:98:22:86:f6:75
  src       = 00:00:00:00:00:11
  type      = LOOP

None
###[ Ethernet ]### 
  dst       = 4e:98:22:86:f6:75
  src       = 00:00:00:00:00:11
  type      = IPv4
###[ IP ]### 
     version   = 4
     ihl       = 5
     tos       = 0x0
     len       = 28
     id        = 1
     flags     = 
     frag      = 0
     ttl       = 5
     proto     = udp
     chksum    = 0xe9c2
     src       = 192.168.1.101
     dst       = 10.0.0.1
     \options   \
###[ UDP ]### 
        sport     = 21608
        dport     = 26995
        len       = 8297
        chksum    = 0x7320
###[ Padding ]### 
           load      = 'a test'

None
.
Sent 1 packets.
success is None
```

And this is what wireshark currently looks like
[image]
[image]

I am not sure if the problem is because the checksum values do not align, but any help creating this packet would be appreciated

Comment: changing `success = send(packet)` to `success = srp(packet)` successfully sends and ARP message to host2, but the IP packet is not sent

Comment: This has a bunch of problems. It looks like your ethernet frame is in a broadcast ethernet frame, and that appears to be a mistake. The IPv4 packet length is 28, but that will be too short because there are 20 bytes of IPv4 header and 8 bytes of UDP header, with nothing left over for the UDP payload. The UDP length of 8297 if far too large for the 8 bytes of UDP header and the payload. You probably want to set the (optional) UDP checksum to `0`. I'm not sure why you are mixing ARP and UDP.

Comment: @RonMaupin The code above is just some practice work because I am in my first networking class at school. Our assignment was to implement more in c, but I was just trying to get the basics down in python because it doesn't require as much perfection due to the the scapy module. Thanks for the additional info, I'll keep working on what I have :) networking is definitely not my strong suite so I've been trying a lot to keep up.